# How to return an empty ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, collections, properties, readonly

In my domain object I am mapping a 1:M relationship with an IList property.

For a good isolation, I make it read-only in this way:

```
private IList<PName> _property;
public ReadOnlyCollection<PName> Property
{
    get
    {
        if (_property!= null)
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<PName>(new List<PName>(this._property));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like ReadOnlyCollection very much but found no interface solution for making the collection read-only.

Now I want to edit the property declaration to make it return empty list and not `null` when it's empty, so I edited it in this way:

```
if (_property!= null)
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<PName>(new List<PName>(this._property));
}
else
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<PName>(new List<PName>());
}
```

but `Property` is always null when I get it in my test.

Comment: where are you getting it? How are you trying to get it? what is `_strutture`? this is not enough information for us to help you

Comment: Put a break point and debug. Does the debugger reach the `else` part? If you return `new [something]` can't see any way it can be null unless you get exception and silently ignore it somewhere...

Comment: _strutture is a paste error, now i fix it, the way i get it is quite difficult since i use a fluent constructor that involves creation of other 4 required object to get it. Suppose that i simply create an instance of this object without any 'Property' specified and in debug i see that 'Property' property is null (in my test i assert that it's must be equals to an empty Ilist and get : 
  Expected: <empty>
  But was:  null

Comment: it's strange that all the way the return value is `new ReadOnlyCollection...` how could it become null?

Comment: In .Net 8, we get `ReadOnlyCollection<T>.Empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set a default value to the IList

```
private IList<PName> _property = new IList<PName>();
public ReadOnlyCollection<PName> Property
{
    get
    {
        return _property
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe new List<PName>(); since IList can't be instanciated. now i try it

Comment: found! was an error in my constructor, i assigned to the property a variable that was null :). can't your code be withoud the IF (...) I like the idea of the dafault

Comment: @gt.guybrush yes, you are right it doesn't need the if statement since it will never be null

Answer (score 9):

As it's readonly and empty, it's safe to store this in a static:

```
private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<PName> EmptyPNames = new List<PName>().AsReadOnly();
```

Then reuse it anywhere you need it, e.g.:

```
if (_property!= null)
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<PName>(new List<PName>(this._property));
}    
else
{
    return EmptyPNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use IEnumerable instead of ReadOnlyCollection :

```
private IList<PName> _property = new List<PName>();
public IEnumerable<PName> Property
{
    get
    {
        return _property;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your methods or properties return `IEnumerable<T>`, it may be unclear for developers consuming your API, whether it's materialized collection or LINQ sequence. `ReadOnlyCollection` is a clear message and makes your code self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution is to edit the class constructor in this way:

```
public MyObject (IList<PName> property)
{
  this._property = property ?? new List<PName>();
}
```